# Postgresql: Create a new user with no privileges?

Tags: postgresql, roles, privileges

I'm just learning PostgreSQL. Every time I create users, they seem to have the full privileges to do anything in any database:

```bsh
$ sudo useradd fool # create the user "fool" in the system
# And in postgresql, as restrictively as possible
$ sudo -u postgres createuser fool --no-superuser --no-createdb --no-createrole --no-inherit
$ sudo -u fool psql postgres # but it can still connect to the "postgres" db
postgres=> drop table ids; # and delete tables
DROP TABLE
```

I tried creating the user through [the `create user` PostgreSQL command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-createuser.html) rather than the [command-line tool](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/app-createuser.html) but it had exactly the same effect.

How can I create a user that only has privileges to access its own database? Or do I have to specifically revoke all permissions after creating the user? 'Cos that kinda sucks from a security perspective - it's easy to accidentally forget (or just not know it's necessary) to revoke permissions for new users.

Comment: All roles are "members" of the pseudo-role `PUBLIC`. And by default `PUBLIC` has many privileges. My practice is to revoke all privileges from `PUBLIC` where I need and grant various combinations to specific roles. A recent addition helps with that - [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html). Another, not so flexible but easier, method is the [`CONNECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) privilege.

Comment: Actually I just found this duplicate question (oops): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884020/why-new-user-in-postgresql-can-connect-to-all-databases

Comment: @MilenA.Radev do you know of an article that could walk me through setting up my default roles and privileges so that when I create a new user the will have full access to their own database but cannot even connect to anyone else's?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev Post that as an answer

Comment: @RobinWinslow You just need to `REVOKE CONNECT ON eachdatabase FROM public;` and/or drop the `public` schema in the DBs. `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` might help with this. It's kind of annoying that these default grants exist, but people would complain even more if they didn't - as it is there's lots of complaint that Pg is "hard to set up".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All roles are "members" of the pseudo-role `PUBLIC`. And by default `PUBLIC` has many privileges. My practice is to revoke all privileges from `PUBLIC` where I need and grant various combinations to specific roles. A recent addition helps with that - [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html). Another, not so flexible but easier, method is the [`CONNECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) privilege.