# User can always connect to the database [POSTGRES]

Tags: postgresql, authentication, psql, sql-grant

I connect with the user "Postgres" and I create one user:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE db_example ;
postgres=# CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'user123';
postgres=# REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db_example FROM user;
REVOKE
postgres=# \q
```

later, I try to connect with the user "user" to "db_example":

> root@debian:/home/debian# psql -d db_example -U user -h localhost

```
psql (9.4.9)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

db_example=>
```

Why can I connect to the user "user" to "db_example"?

Thanks for the help and good day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why new user in PostgreSQL can connect to all databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884020/why-new-user-in-postgresql-can-connect-to-all-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `PUBLIC` (i.e. everybody) has that privilege by default.

To remove that, run

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db_example FROM PUBLIC;
```

Run `\l+` to see the privileges currently set on the databases.
An empty setting means the default value: the owner can do everything, and `PUBLIC` can connect.